# Не понимаю вложенность классов/селекторов в css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, media-queries

Делаю меню, которое должно выплывать, когда экран меньше заданного.
Все работает как надо, вопрос в другом, почему стили из медизапроса срабатывают только если прописать как сейчас - div.menu li?
На примере все поймете (медизапрос в самом конце CSS стилей)

```js
$(function() {

  $('#hideButton').click(function() {
    $("#mySidenav").css("width", "367px");
    $("#hideButton").fadeOut(10);
  });

  $('.closeBtn').click(function() {
    $("#mySidenav").css("width", "0");
    $("#hideButton").fadeIn(3000);
  });

});
```

```css
.menu li {
  min-width: 6px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 13px;
  left: 1rem;
  color: #acc;
  font-size: 2rem;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  /*background-color: black;
border: 1px solid black;
-webkit-border-radius: ;
        border-radius: 100%;*/
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(42, 101, 130, 0.56);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  text-shadow: 0 0 30px lightgrey;
  /*background-color: rgba(42, 101, 130, 0.69);*/
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 544px) {
  div.menu li {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <ul id="hideButton">
    <li> &#9776;</li>
    <li> &#9776;</li>
    <li> &#9776;</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closeBtn">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

просто методом тыка умудрился найти нужную комбинацию, всегда хотел узнать как именно работает эта"вложенность" или как это называется?
то есть почему именно срабатывает только комбинация div.menu li? и что важно если только без пробела между div и .menu почему не работает применение только класса или класса и li (.menu li)?

Comment: `.menu li` в вашем примере тоже прекрасно работает

Comment: видимо только у вас) у меня в хроме нет

Comment: Ответ на Ваш вопрос не знаю, а на счет методов, подскажу). Чтобы не тратить много времени на селекторы в медиа запросах - скопируйте их (селекторы) прямо из консоли.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если к одному элементу одновременно применяются противоречивые стилевые правила, то более высокий приоритет имеет правило у которого значение специфичности селектора больше.

`div.menu li` - специфичность 12

`.menu li` - специфичность 11

[Спецификация](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity)

[Калькулятор](https://specificity.keegan.st/)